# Internal error on batch prediction job. Reproduction conditions are unidentified

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-cloud-ai-platform-pipelines

I trained some tabular forecasting model and executed batch prediction jobs with Vertex AI, then sometimes the following error occurred 30-60 minutes after the start of the jobs.

```
Internal error occurred. Please retry in a few minutes. If you still experience errors, contact Vertex AI.
```

As the message mentioned, I retried the next day with same data and then I got the prediction job succeed.
However, I have seen this error from time to time with Vertex AI.
I cannot identify the reproduction conditions.
I cannot find the logs of the job execution.

What causes this error in Vertex AI?
How can I avoid this errror?

Resource name:
projects/832409671062/locations/us-central1/batchPredictionJobs/3813678620929425408